# using reg exp to check if test string is of a fixed format

Tags: python, regex

I want to make sure using regex that a string is of the format-  "999.999-A9-Won" and without any white spaces or tabs or newline characters.

1. There may be 2 or 3 numbers in the range 0 - 9.
2. Followed by a period '.'
3. Again followed by 2 or 3 numbers in the range 0 - 9
4. Followed by a hyphen, character 'A' and a number between 0 - 9 .
5. This can be followed by anything.

Example: 87.98-A8-abcdef

The code I have come up until now is:

```
testString = "87.98-A1-help"
regCompiled = re.compile('^[0-9][0-9][.][0-9][0-9][-A][0-9][-]*');
checkMatch = re.match(regCompiled, testString);
if checkMatch:
    print ("FOUND")
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

This doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what I'm missing and also the problem here is I'm not checking for white spaces, tabs and new line characters and also hard-coded the number for integers before and after decimal.

Comment: I'd loose those semicolons; makes it look like javascript.. :-P

Comment: LOL! Yeah, Martijn. Got those after coding in Java!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `{m,n}` you can specify the number of times a pattern can repeat, and the `\d` character class matches all digits. The `\S` character class matches anything that is *not* whitespace. Using these your regular expression can be simplified to:

```
re.compile(r'\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}-A\d-\S*\Z')
```

Note also the `\Z` anchor, making the `\S*` expression match all the way to the end of the string. No whitespace (newlines, tabs, etc.) are allowed here. If you combine this with the [`.match()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) you assure that all characters in your tested string conform to the pattern, nothing more, nothing less. See [`search()` vs. `match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for more information on `.match()`.

A small demonstration:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\d{2,3}\.\d{2,3}-A\d-\S*\Z')
>>> pattern.match('87.98-A1-help')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1026905e0>
>>> pattern.match('123.45-A6-no whitespace allowed')
>>> pattern.match('123.45-A6-everything_else_is_allowed')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1026905e0>
```

Comment: -1 (a) The initial `^` is redundant when used with `match` (b) `$` matches a newline; use `\Z` instead.

Comment: @JohnMachin: Indeed; forgot about the $ and newline issue; I've updated the answer with `\Z` and using search instead.

Comment: Still -1 (a) `\Z$` ??? Use `\Z` INSTEAD OF `$`, not AS WELL AS `$` (b) Using `search` with initial `^` and terminal `\Z` is baroque and also inefficient -- the Python `re` implementation continues searching at offset 1, 2, etc if the first search fails -- it doesn't recognise that `^` means it can fail immediately.

Comment: @JohnMachin: Sorry, I was somewhat distracted and in a hurry. All fixed up now, with additional info on search() vs. match().

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at your regular expression. If you want:

> "2 or 3 numbers in the range 0 - 9"

then you can't start your regular expression with `'^[0-9][0-9][.]` because that will only match strings with exactly two integers at the beginning. A second issue with your regex is at the end: `[0-9][-]*` - if you wish to match anything at the end of the string then you need to finish your regular expression with `.*` instead. **Edit**: see Martijn Pieters's answer regarding the whitespace in the regular expressions.

Here is an updated regular expression:

```
testString = "87.98-A1-help"
regCompiled = re.compile('^[0-9]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2,3}-A[0-9]-.*');
checkMatch = re.match(regCompiled, testString);
if checkMatch:
    print ("FOUND")
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

Not everything needs to be enclosed inside `[` and `]`, in particular when you know the character(s) that you wish to match (such as the part `-A`). Furthermore:

- the notation `{m,n}` means: match at least `m` times and at most `n` times, and
- to explicitly match a dot, you need to escape it: that's why there is `\.` in the regular expression above.

Comment: Your regular expression would allow whitespace beyond the last dash.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks, I've updated the answer to include a note about this.